# twisted wait for another client

Tags: python, twisted

This is my render_GET function in class inherited from resource.Resource in twisted HTTP server:

```
    def render_GET(self, request):
           file = request.args['file'][0]
           altitude, azimuth, distance = request.args['position'][0].split(",")
           self.update_render(file, altitude, azimuth, distance, request.args['clientID'][0])
           # update_render() starts a thread that contacts this server again and POSTs data once done
           self.add_client(request.args['clientID'][0])

           while not self.client_data[request.args['clientID'][0]]:
                 # I GET STUCK HERE - the thread CANT send data to this dict since server is locked in this loop
                 time.sleep(0.5)

           return "DONE"
```

What happens is that I need the twisted server to wait until function `update_render` does something (this function is asynchronous, so by calling `self.update_render()` I just start it, not sure when the actual data is written. The return data of `update_render()` is written in self.client_data dict.

I need to detect the content of this dict in a loop BUT I am stuck there - it seems the server is locked in this loop BUT I need it to respond to other clients (they asynchronously fill self.client_data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never want to write a while loop like that in a Twisted-using application.

Ideally, you want a better API than `update_render` - one that returns a Deferred.  A Deferred gives you a uniform, composable, convenient API for managing callbacks.  Callbacks are fairly central to programming with Twisted.

`update_render` should use the `Deferred`'s `callback` method once it gets the client data - instead of putting it into `self.client_data`.  By using the `Deferred`, it plays nicely in the event-driven system of Twisted.  A callback you (the caller) attach to the `Deferred` can send the result to the client.

Twisted Web has a slight quirk in that you'll need to return `twisted.web.server.NOT_DONE_YET` from the `render_GET` method to let the server know that the response is forthcoming.

Have a look at [Twisted Web In 60 Seconds](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/index.html) for some examples of asynchronously generating responses.